# Date/String Comparison in Impala doesn't work (always return false)

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera, impala

So i am currently writing an impala query which essentially group the data based on several column, and take the value of the rest of the column based on the most recent ones. However, as I want to group the data based on the date, the query always return false when comparing the data.

My code is as below. If I didn't include the tstamp comparison, the code works just fine, but unable to group it based on the date.

```
`select * from mytab as x 
    where x.tstamp = 
    (select max(y.tstamp) from mytab as y 
            where x.id_ = y.id_ and x.id = y.id and 
            to_date(x.tstamp) = to_date(y.tstamp));
`
```

and the data is as below. The data below is just a snippet of the real data, which contains data from many days and have more columns.

```
    tstamp                   id         id_
    2018-06-07 06:39:26.470  10002071   5438221
    2018-06-07 06:39:26.533  10002071   5438221
    2018-06-07 06:39:35.223  10002071   5438221
    2018-06-07 06:39:35.343  10002071   5438222
    2018-06-07 06:39:39.087  10002071   5438222
    2018-06-07 06:39:43.390  10002071   5438222
    2018-06-07 06:39:43.417  10002071   6268470
    2018-06-07 06:39:44.700  10002071   6268470
    2018-06-07 06:39:48.573  10002071   6268470
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(tstamp) over (partition by id_, id, to_date(tstamp) as max_tstamp
      from t
     ) t
where tstamp = max_tstamp;
```

That said, your version should work, but this is simpler.